# Group data by timeframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I'm looping through a long list of dictionaries obtained by a MongoDB query in Python:

```
for x in DB[COL].find({'datetime': {'$gte': StartTime}}):
```

Which gives me a list of results like this:

```
{'datetime': 2020-07-05 19:21", 'data': [...]}
{'datetime': 2020-07-05 19:25", 'data': [...]}
{'datetime': 2020-07-05 19:35", 'data': [...]}
```

I need to order this record in 30 minutes intervals, so i need to change `datetime` so that the output is the following:

```
{'datetime': 2020-07-05 19:30", 'data': [...]} //because 19:21 -> 19:30
{'datetime': 2020-07-05 19:30", 'data': [...]} //because 19:25 -> 19:30
{'datetime': 2020-07-05 20:00", 'data': [...]} //because 19:35 -> 20:00
```

How can i do that with Python?

Comment: But then you would have dictionary with repeated keys, don't you tihnk of better putting it into a pandas dataframe before performing operations?

Comment: Yes this is indeed a problem. Might have to use a Pandas dataframe indeed

Comment: If you can get it into a dataframe and edit your question, I'll help you, this way it seems like it will be more trouble in the futurethan it will actually help you solve the problem

Comment: This is right. Let me see if i can do it with a dataframe without needing extra help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach. I'd have a list of docs and change them depending on their minutes;

```
for doc in docs:
    date = doc['datetime']
    if date.minute > 30:
        doc['datetime'] = dt.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour + 1, 0)
    else:
        doc['datetime'] = dt.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour, 0)
```

From there you can just use pandas dataframe .groupby method and group by datetime.
That looks mighty ugly and you can definitely clean it up, but it should work.

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to do it for now. I need to get this data into a dataframe and work with it